# joint probability and conditional probability of 2 events

Tags: probability

I'm doing a self study on probability, and am somewhat confused. The problem below is obtained from an example given in the free [OpenIntro stats book](https://leanpub.com/openintro-statistics), page 105.

say that 4% of woman get breast cancer. Mammogram is used to predict breast cancer, and it has 11% false negative rate, and 7 % positive rate.

If i'm drawing a tree for this probability

```
Woman's Pro.        Mamogram result 
of getting BC       (Conditional Prob)
(Marginal Prob.)    P(Positive(or Neg)|(BC or not BC)      

4% (BC) --------   89%(positive=predict BC)
        |            
        --------   11%(negative=predict no BC)



96%(NO BC)------   7% (+)
          |
          ------  93% (-)
```

To calculate a joint probability that someone has cancer(denoted as C) and the Mamogram predicts right(i.e. positive, denoted as M+) is:

```
P(C and M+) = P(M+ | C) * P(C) = 89% * 4%
```

I'm confused because this looks like it's calculating the joint probability of 2 independent events. When A and B are 2 independent events, they are calculated as P(A) * P(B). In this case, this is assuming, P(M+|C) is independent from P(C). Is this right? is P(M+|C) independent from P(C)?

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Why is this not calculated using joint probability of 2 dependent events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Mathematics StackExchange!

Remember that the definition of the conditional probability is:
$$\mathbb P(A|B):=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(B)}.$$
You only have to multiply both sides of the definition with $\mathbb P(B)$ to get the reason why $\mathbb P(A\cap B)$ does indeed equal $\mathbb P(A|B)\mathbb P(B)$. The fact that this is the same procedure that you use for independent events is, as far as I am aware, purely coincidental.